# get td column value when click on image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have table in razor code with tag  that is rendered with each record in table. I struggling to find way when user click on this image, app get store id against the clicked row (in jquery) and alert id.

```
<table id="grid">
 <thead> 
 <tr>
    <th data-field="store_id">Store ID</th>
    <th data-field="address">Address</th>
    <th data-field="postcode">post Code</th>
    <th data-field="city">City</th>
    <th data-field="country">Country</th>
    <th data-sortable="false">Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

 <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.storeID)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.address)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.postcode)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.city)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Country)</td>
    <td><img class="img" src="~/Images/delete.png" /></td>
   <!-- <td> <input type="button" class="b1" value ="Press Me" /></td>-->
  </tr>
  }
 </tbody>
</table>
```

here is javascript code using jQuery

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".img").click(function () {

         var a = $(this).  ?????

         alert("clicked " + a);

         var store = { storeID: '3' }
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Master/processJsonRequest",
             data: JSON.stringify({ model: store }),
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (response) {
                 alert(response);
             }
         });
     });
 });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".img").click(function () {
    var storeId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    alert("clicked " + storeId);

    // fire off your ajax...
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/phujq/)